# Passing JSON array values as JQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to pass JSON array values into my javascript file and use the values as selectors to call methods on corresponding html divs.

for example:

```
function clickEvents(items) {
for (var r = 0; r < items.length; r++) {    
    var omega = items[r].id +;

     $(omega).click(function() {
        alert('Thanks for adding item number #' + omega ' to your cart!');
    });
}
```

where my JSON looks like this:

```
 {
"Items" : [{
        "header: "apple",
        "id": 5000
      }, {
         "header": "banana",
         "id":5001
      }, {
         "header": "pear",
         "id": 5002
      }]
 }
```

unfortunately, its not working properly. I can't seem to get the selectors to match up. Does anyone know the proper syntax for this type of approach or have ideas for other approaches?

when i do this, it works:

```
function clickEvents(items) {
   $('#5001').click(function() {
      alert('hi');
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things.

First, you can't start an ID with a number. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id

Second, you need to concatenate the `#` in the selector if you are selecting using ID attribute.

**Here's an example:** http://jsfiddle.net/3BBtU/

```
function clickEvents(items) {
    for (var r = 0; r < items.length; r++) { 

          // removed the stray "+" at the end
        var omega = items[r].id;

            // If you wanted to add an attribute to each element, do it here.
        $('#' + omega).attr('someAttribute', 'some value');

            // Wrap handler assignment in a closure, passing "omega" in so that
            //      when it fires, it is referencing the correct value of "omega"
        (function(o) {
                 // concatenate "#" to the ID for a proper ID selector
             $('#' + o).click(function() {

                  // You were missing the second + operator in this concatenation
                alert('Thanks for adding item number #' + o + ' to your cart!');
             });
        })(omega);
    }
}

    // Modify IDs so that they do not start with a number
var obj = {
    "Items" : [{
            "header": "apple",
            "id": "d5000"
          }, {
             "header": "banana",
             "id": "d5001"
          }, {
             "header": "pear",
             "id": "d5002"
          }]
     };

    // call the clickEvents() passing in the Items from the obj variable
clickEvents(obj.Items);​
```

---

**EDIT:**

- Added an example
- Corrected a mistake where I had `functions` instead of `var`.
- Corrected one more issue. I wrapped the handler assignment in a closure because the `omega` variable was being used inside the handler in the concatenation in `.alert()`, which means that it was referencing the latest value update of `omega` when a click fired it.

Comment: so the id needs to be of type string? right now they are integers

Comment: A question about the first thing: start an ID with a number works; is it NOT standard?

Comment: @fordays, @s.susini - Whether it is a string or an integer, it is invalid HTML to start an ID with a number. They must start with a letter. It may work in some browsers, but perhaps not in others.

Comment: what about creating your own in-house attribute tag, for example:

"pid": "k5001"
as an element of an array.

how do I refer to "pid" in a jquery selector after assignment the pid number to the html tag?

Comment: @fordays - Why? If you're going to start it with "k", then it is valid for an ID. You could use your approach, but it is faster to use actual valid ID attributes for lookup. A lot faster. Note that I'm talking about the ID for the HTML elements. Those must start with a letter.

Comment: @fordays - See my latest update (or the link to the example). If you're going to reference the `omega` variable inside the handler, then you need to pass it in via a `closure`. If you're adding an attribute to each element, then I would do that in the `for` loop, but *outside* the click handler, so it happens *before* you click.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is going wrong? You're missing a quotation mark after the last "id" in your sample, but maybe it's just a typo...(?)

Comment: i fixed the typo, however, I need help getting the selector syntax correct when I call $(omega).click


Do I need to make a change in the assignment of omega or in the selector syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something like: `$("#"+omega)`.
You are asking for an id, isn't it!?

```
function clickEvents(items) {
for (var r = 0; r < items.length; r++) {    
    var omega = items[r].id;

     $("#"+omega).click(function() {
        alert('Thanks for adding item number #' + omega ' to your cart!');
    });
}
```

In fact th $() function in this case thake a string the is a validCSS selector.